# Precompiling a js.erb file or load without precompile it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a stupid problem: I have a javascript file which has some javascript constants (used in all javascript code) that are "fetched" from rails.

The code is simple:

```
var CrossJavascriptSettings = {
  desktop_columns: <%= Rails.configuration.extjs_desktop[:icon_columns] %>,
  recaptcha_public_key: '<%= Recaptcha.configuration.public_key %>',
  tasks_icon_image: '<%= image_path('icons/Clock.png') %>',
  no_image: '<%= image_path('icons/Delete.png') %>',
  loading_image: '<%= image_path('ext-icons/loading.gif') %>',

  loading_image_preloaded: new Image().src = '<%= image_path('ext-icons/loading.gif') %>',
  no_image_preloaded: new Image().src = '<%= image_path('icons/Delete.png') %>',
  tasks_icon_image_preloaded: new Image().src = '<%= image_path('icons/Clock.png') %>',

  available_roles: <%= Rails.configuration.available_roles.each_with_index.collect { |element, index| [index, element] }.as_json %>,

  organizations_logo_path: '/assets/organizations/logos/'
};
```

The problem is that my file doesn't get precompiled, and this is quite strange because inside the file, I'm using things that are only config options, no databsae or similar.

So my question is, how can I solve this issue? Are there any way to force compiling of that file with required constants or are there any way to load it without being compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved "in the other way". You can't do it, you need to move those constants in your application.html.erb or load them through AJAX.

Comment: Running 'rake assets:precompile' precompiled my js.erb into application-...js

Comment: Are you using rails 4? That may be the difference.